# Ubuntu Gnome : Move the mouse with Synergy

Tags: mouse, ubuntu-gnome, synergy

I've got 2 laptops, one with Windows and the other with Ubuntu Gnome.
I'd like to use my Windows as the master.

First, on windows, Synergy switch on Linux when my mouse is 300px next the edge of my screen. Not a problem, I mapped the 'next/previous page' buttons to switch without the mouse.

But I got a big problem I need to solve : on Linux, my mouse don't move. The keystroke and the mouse buttons work, but not the movement.

Can you help me ?
Thanks for your answers !

**Edit** : The cursor is stuck on the bottom-right corner on the Linux machine.

Comment: Are you able to ping from one computer to the other?  Are you sure you have the configuration set up correctly?

Comment: Sure, I said I can type and click.

Comment: Whoops, you're right.  Missed that.   :)

Comment: What version are you using?